# ASP.NET Cache vs SQL Performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, caching

**Shorter version**:

I have a cache that stores mostly datatables using the `MemoryCache.Default`. If I have a SQL Server database with say ~1,000 rows, what would be faster:

- Storing the datatable in cache, checking the cache, and falling back to SQL Server?
- Hitting SQL Server for every request?

**Longer version**:

I have a cache implemented that currently returns a datatable for common SQL Server queries used throughout a site (example: a drop down list of insurance agency types). These datatables are currently rather static data that doesn't need to be all that up-to-date since they generally only change the site gets updated and the application pool is recycled.

I am now considering extending this caching to include datatables that require parameters for a SQL Server stored procedure to run. However, these tables are all rather small (~1,000 rows or less with typically less than 5 columns).

However, I am unsure of the performance implications. What I am thinking of doing is pulling most of these tables in to the `MemoryCache.Default` and then just using LINQ to return the correct datatable from the parameters. Small semi-pseudocode example of what I was thinking:

```
Function FetchFromCache(nameOfObject As String, someFilterVar)
   Dim cache As ObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default
   Dim dtFetched As DataTable = TryCast(cache(nameOfObject), DataTable)
   If dtFetched Is Nothing Then
     'Code here to fill in the datatable from SQL and put it in the cache
   End If
   Dim query = (From obj in dtFetched
                Where obj.Field(Of Integer)("fieldToTest") = someFilterVar
                Select obj)
   Return query.CopyToDataTable()
End Function
```

Is this a terrible idea? I'm a little worried that something like this would actually have worse performance than just hitting the SQL Server which has it's own cache, optimization, etc. Please excuse the very rough provided code.

Comment: In memory is always faster, for 1000 rows the difference should be negligible unless your database has an absurd amount of network latency to communicate.

Comment: So say, for example, that we have factor tables in our database that have ~1,000 - ~1500 rows. These factors are lookup up by an 'nRevisionNum'. Would it be beneficial to cache these if they are getting hit multiple times on multiple page loads for nearly every user?

Comment: For a single page load, nothing really should be read multiple times that's one of the clearest indicators of bad design. Regarding your intended question, I seek to limit all remote resource calls through caching where ever **reasonable** to one per minute, 5 minutes, 60 minutes, or 6 hours (dependent on underlying data)